type convertion in JS
Is there any practical difference between Number() and + other than performance or intent?
Tried googling, searching for posts from other sites, and asking AI but couldn't find any practical or technical answer.
The below code is from AI, and in all cases, the output is always the same. Couldn't find any practical difference.
console.log("Unary + Operator vs Number Constructor");

// Conversion of Numeric Strings
let str1 = "42";
console.log("Unary +: ", +str1);         // Output: 42
console.log("Number: ", Number(str1));   // Output: 42

// Conversion of Non-numeric Strings
let str2 = "abc";
console.log("Unary +: ", +str2);         // Output: NaN
console.log("Number: ", Number(str2));   // Output: NaN

// Handling Empty Strings
let str3 = "";
console.log("Unary +: ", +str3);         // Output: 0
console.log("Number: ", Number(str3));   // Output: 0

// Handling Strings with Whitespace
let str4 = "  ";
console.log("Unary +: ", +str4);         // Output: 0
console.log("Number: ", Number(str4));   // Output: 0

// Handling Boolean Strings
let str5 = "true";
console.log("Unary +: ", +str5);         // Output: NaN
console.log("Number: ", Number(str5));   // Output: NaN

// Handling Special Numeric Strings
console.log("Unary + Infinity: ", +"Infinity");       // Output: Infinity
console.log("Unary -Infinity: ", +"-Infinity");       // Output: -Infinity
console.log("Unary NaN: ", +"NaN");                    // Output: NaN

console.log("Number Infinity: ", Number("Infinity"));  // Output: Infinity
console.log("Number -Infinity: ", Number("-Infinity")); // Output: -Infinity
console.log("Number NaN: ", Number("NaN"));            // Output: NaN

// Conversion of Boolean Values
console.log("Unary + true: ", +true);  // Output: 1
console.log("Unary + false: ", +false); // Output: 0

console.log("Number true: ", Number(true));  // Output: 1
console.log("Number false: ", Number(false)); // Output: 0


There is a slight difference between these two conversion methods-

Number constructor is explicit and readable while unary operator is prone to create defects in code.

Number() constructor has better error handling e.g. -


In case of Big int
console.log(Number(20n)) // Output 20
console.log(+20n) // Uncaught error : TypeError: Cannot convert a BigInt value to a number

Apart from above point I couldn't find any major differences.
I hope, it will answer your question !

Thanks for the response. i didnt know "+" wont  working with BigInt . are there any other scenerios where on of these is more suitable than the other?( excluding speed and readablity and similar factors)

can you pls mention any defects example.? Thanks

In the question you have asked about the Number coercion to primitive. Unary operator and Number() function both doing the same thing except the Number() has better error handling.  Both will work same for all datatypes even with Octal, Hexadecimal and binary numbers as well.

When Number() is called as a function (without new), it returns value coerced to a number primitive. Specially, BigInts values are converted to numbers instead of throwing. If value is absent, it becomes 0.  ( Reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/Number#return_value)

The performance difference is generally negligible, but in performance-critical applications, the unary + operator might be slightly faster because it is less verbose and involves less function call overhead.
There are a few similarities in both approaches,
Both will convert string numerical to numbers & non-numerical will return NaN

let str = "42";
console.log(+str);        // 42
console.log(Number(str)); // 42

let str = "abc";
console.log(+str);        // NaN
console.log(Number(str)); // NaN


The same goes for empty strings and boolean values. an empty string will return a 0 and a boolean will return 0 or 1. Difference comes in the objects and symbols


Thanks for the response.. ive checked almost all the scenerios i can think of and tried coersion using both the methods( for Number type only) .. but the OP was always the same.. other than factors like performance or readibility, are there any practical difference ? i mean is there any scenerio where these two give different answer ?

Not according to my experience so far, but I would prefer casting with types. At the end of the day, the typescript language is solely developed and used to avoid cases like this
